# Logging in the user using simple PHP but database query fails

Tags: php, sql

I tried to query my database to return the user with the matching id but it seems the query doesn’t properly query the database because no action is taken. The page simply refreshes with no messages and displays the login form again. I have also tried using the mysqli_fetch_array() function to return the matching rows in the database but it also failed.

```
       <?php

       if (isset ($_POST['username']) && (isset ($_POST['password']))){
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST ['password'];

       //encrypting the password with md5 hashing
       $password_hash = md5($password);

       if (!empty ($username) && (!empty($password))) {


      $query= "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = ‘$username' 
      AND password = '$password_hash' ";

        if ($query_run = mysqli_query ($mysql_conn, $query)) {
            $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($query_run);

            if ($query_num_rows == 0) { //checks to see if username and password exists in database
                echo 'Invalid username or password.';
            }
            else if ($query_num_rows == 1) {
                echo 'OK';
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
       <form action = "<?php echo $current_file; ?>" method = "POST">
       Username: <br>
       <input type = "textarea" name = "username"><br><br>
       Password: <br>
       <input type = "Password" name = "password"><br><br>
       <input type = "submit" value = "Log in">
       </form>
```

Comment: there must be something else going on then. Please show 1st the login form, 2nd the whole script the shown snippet is from.

Comment: _important (but still a) sidenote:_ you shouldn't save and compare the password as you do now. Use password_hash() and password_verify()

Comment: _more sidenotes:_ Your query is open to sql injections. Use Prepared statements.

Comment: _another one_: I hope this is for learning purposes only. Don't try to roll out your own authentication system, rather use one of the existing authentication frameworks/plugins/.. that are secure and maintained by a community.

Comment: Possible typo, you have a "curly" quote  `’` after `@username` not a "straight" quote `'`

Comment: thanks @Jeff for the guidance. I am doing this for learning purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested the following and it works fine. Note it is just checking username as it is below.

```
 <?php

    //connect to the database - $mysql_conn as connection

    if (isset ($_POST['username']) && (isset ($_POST['password']))){
       $username = $_POST['username'];
       $password = $_POST ['password'];

        //encrypting the password with md5 hashing
        $password_hash = md5($password);

        if (!empty ($username) && (!empty($password))) {

            $query= "SELECT userID FROM crUsers WHERE userName = '$username';";

            //$query= "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password_hash';";
            $query= "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username = '$username';"; //Checking just username

            $query_run = mysqli_query ($mysql_conn, $query);
            $query_num_rows = mysqli_num_rows ($query_run);

            if ($query_num_rows == 0) { 
                echo 'Invalid username or password.';
            }
            else if ($query_num_rows == 1) {
               echo 'OK';
            }
            else {
               echo 'More than one user with these credentials';
            }
        }
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>

<body>

   <form method = "POST">
       Username: <br>
       <input type = "text" name = "username"><br><br>
       Password: <br>
       <input type = "Password" name = "password"><br><br>
       <input type = "submit" value = "Log in">
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: good catch, but I think a "Try" would be better as a comment, don't you?

Comment: @Jeff Sorry - I don't follow. I agree prepared statements would be better, but just answering the question.

Comment: @RGriffiths Thanks. After your suggested change it shows me the block of echo that says invalid username but now even after i put the correct credentials it says invalid username or password. I am also getting this warning message after the change: Warning: Mysqli_Num_Rows() Expects Parameter 1 To Be Mysqli_Result, Boolean Given

Comment: Perhaps echo the $query and then directly check the query string is working in your SQL.It would suggest an error in the SQL query - maybe a wrong field name.

Comment: Look out for that curly quote after the `$username` parameter.... it should be `'$username'` not `'$username’`

Comment: @JonP Well spotted

Comment: good eyes @JonP for picking that up! fixed it but didn’t work tho

Comment: @RGriffiths i have checked the query string my SQL and it returned the row with the user and password. I have verified the field names to be correct also. But when i fill in the login form i still get invalid username or password. I have also tried to just accept username in the form to see if it is a username or password issue but still invalid, i did the same for the password and it’s the same result.

Comment: Are you using an hashing algorithm on the password? You need to use the same when checking the password is correct.

Comment: Yes i am. I tried it both ways but still nothing. I’m really shooting blanks here.